# Windows10: Cannot create a registry key with extension ".exe"

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I'm trying to apply the steps given in this anser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503593/how-to-reduce-visual-studio-build-process-priority-to-prevent-unresponsive-system.

For this, i want to create a registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\cl.exe` plus some sub key and values.
But registry editor won't let me create a key name that contains ".exe" or rename it to such a name.

[image]

I can create or rename to `cl.exa` or `cl.exer` - just `cl.exe` will not be accepted!
Neither is `some-random-nonsense.exe`. Which shows that it is not linked to any existing processes or file name.

Why is this and how can i circumvent it?

I checked i am the owner of the registry key and i started regedit as Administrator and have local admin privileges. Permissions say i have "Full control" on the item.

Comment: And which error you've got?

Comment: @montonero: Added screenshot of the (very unspecific) error message.

Comment: Probably VS or some other process is holding this key. Have you closed VS before renaming? Or try to search a handle with a Process Explorer.

Comment: I think that some registry monitoring process - Windows Defender or some antiviral software,- locks entry rename to such name.

Comment: I use Defender and Visual Studio and I never had this problem - with or without Visual Studio running. I suspect a third-party AV. BTW: You could try ProcessMonitor to at least find out the error code. Not that I think it will help much, it's probably going to be "access denied" :)